# Are Tokenized Fields submitted as an array or string-list in Rails Forms?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tokenize

I have a tokenized field in one of my forms where a user can enter multiple emails to send out invites (for example, generated via [this library](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/))

[image: tokenized fields]

When the user hits "Submit" and the form data is submitted to my Rails controller, how are the various emails submitted? Is it an array of all emails, or is it a long string of emails separated by commas/spaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it can be any of the above - it looks like the tokenizer library doesn't hook into the form "submit" button, so you'll have to implement your own function, which, on submit, collects all of the tokens into something you'd like to have and then sends it to the server

look specifically at the following function, which will help:

`$('#some-token-field-id').tokenfield('getTokens')`

or, alternatively:
`$('#some-token-field-id').tokenfield('getTokens', true)`